# Transistor amplifier with active load in high frequencies

Tags: transistors, amplifier, frequency, current-mirror

I have simple transistor amplifier with active load, problem is I am using the circuit in 1 to 10 MHz range, so as you can see the gain is low in this region. Used transistors are bc337 and bc327. I do need gain around 800.

---

So my question is:

Should I use these transistors and chain more stages to archive desired gain.

**--or--**

Should I use another type of transistors with higher maximum frequency. If yes what kind of?

**The key factor is price.**
[image: schematics]
[image]

Comment: You need DC feedback to stabilize the operating point or one of the transistors will saturate.

Comment: Could you plese explain it in more delay, perhaps send me some example?

Comment: _"I am using the circuit in 1 to 10 MHz range... need gain around 800"_ - need some other specs too. What is the purpose of this circuit?